# Writing a JOIN query with two counts from joined table

Tags: mysql, sql

I've spent a few hours fighting with this, but I can't get the counts to work. Hopefully someone can help?!

I have a project table and task table, linked on the project_id. I can get the project_id, project_name, and the status_id with the query below:

```
SELECT 
    a.project_id, 
    a.project_name,
    b.status_id
FROM project_list as a
INNER JOIN task_list as b
ON a.project_id=b.project_id
```

I'd like to select a single record for each project and add two count fields based on the status_id. In pseudo code:

```
SELECT 
    a.project_id, 
    a.project_name,
    (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM task_list WHERE status_id < 3) as not_completed,
    (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM task_list WHERE status_id = 3) as completed
FROM project_list as a
INNER JOIN task_list as b
ON a.project_id=b.project_id
GROUP BY project_id
```

My create table scripts are below:

```
CREATE TABLE `project_list` (
  `project_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `topic_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `project_name` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`project_id`)
)

CREATE TABLE `task_list` (
  `task_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `project_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `task_name` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `status_id` int(11) DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`task_id`)
)
```

Any help is much appreciated. Thanks!

EDIT: ANSWER:

```
SELECT 
    a.project_id, 
    project_name,
    SUM(status_id != 3) AS not_completed,
    SUM(status_id = 3) AS completed,
    SUM(status_id IS NOT NULL) as total
FROM tasks.project_list as a
INNER JOIN tasks.task_list as b
ON a.project_id=b.project_id
GROUP BY a.project_id
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that in your subqueries you are counting all the rows in the whole table rather than just the rows that have the correct `project_id`. You could fix this by modifying the `WHERE` clause in each of your subqueries.

```
(SELECT COUNT(*)
 FROM task_list AS c
 WHERE c.status_id < 3
 AND a.project_id = c.project_id)
```

However a simpler approach is to use `SUM` with a boolean condition instead of `COUNT` to count the rows that match the condition:

```
SELECT 
    a.project_id, 
    a.project_name,
    SUM(b.status_id < 3) AS not_completed,
    SUM(b.status_id = 3) AS completed,
FROM project_list as a
INNER JOIN task_list as b
ON a.project_id = b.project_id
GROUP BY project_id
```

This works because `TRUE` evaluates to `1` and `FALSE` evaluates to `0`.

Comment: What may not be obvious is that this query will be much easier for the optimiser to optimise. Making it a very nice solution

Comment: Thanks, the query below works, but some of the totals don't add up. Is there any reason they wouldn't? (Man, comment formatting is terrible, sorry..)


SELECT 
    a.project_id, 
    a.project_name,
    SUM(status_id != 3) AS not_completed,
    SUM(status_id = 3) AS completed,
    SUM(status_id) AS total 
FROM tasks.project_list as a
INNER JOIN tasks.task_list as b
ON a.project_id=b.project_id
GROUP BY a.project_id

Comment: @TommyGunn32: Maybe there are rows that have a NULL status? You could add an extra field to count those rows too `SUM(status_id IS NULL)`.

Comment: Thanks Mark. IS NOT NULL gave me the total count below and they add up. Weird result trying to count just the status_id or task_id. I guess the join should be RIGHT? I'll continue playing. Thanks guys!

SELECT 
    a.project_id, 
    project_name,
    SUM(status_id != 3) AS not_completed,
    SUM(status_id = 3) AS completed,
    SUM(status_id IS NOT NULL) as total
FROM tasks.project_list as a
INNER JOIN tasks.task_list as b
ON a.project_id=b.project_id
GROUP BY a.project_id